# Remove extra padding on active tab [wp]

Tags: css, wordpress, tabs, woocommerce, padding

I have a WP eCommerce site running woocommerce. On the product pages, there are currently 3 tabs "Description, Details, Shipping". For some reason, when a tab is active there is some padding that exist on the right of the text. I would like to remove this since it causes issues on mobile and tablet where this padding overlaps the  next tab (for details - shipping tab). I would like the with to be that of text itself. I am unable myself to find the right class or div to do this.

Here is a screenshot to further explain:

http://postimg.org/image/ctyawyzyv/

Website product url: http://museiam.ca/product/black-cut-sleeve-sweater/

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Solved your problem ?I guess Website link is in maintenance mode.

Answer (score 0):

You have width's set on the li's based on media queries. You also have a WHOLE bunch of !important rules set everywhere... might want to rewrite quite a bit of that.